# Display all users under all OUs in active directory using adLDAP?

Tags: php, adldap

How can i display all users under all OUs in active directory using adLDAP? I am using adLDAP of php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm currently using this...

```
$adldap->user()->all()
```

[from the documentation](http://adldap.sourceforge.net/wiki/doku.php?id=documentation_user_functions#all_includedescription_false_search_sorted_true)